# What is the syntax for VBA ContentTypeProperties for parent 'Document Set'-name?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I'm trying to get the ContentTypeProperties in VBA (to populate a metadata-value in a cell in Excel) from the parent 'Document set' in which the Excel-file exists. Does anybody know how to do this en which Value I need?

I already could get the custom added metadata columns that I added to the document-set, but can't find the standard 'title' or 'name' property of that Document Set?

```
Function GetDocProp(DocProp As String) As String
GetDocProp = ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(DocProp)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ContentTypeProperties` property, as per documentation, returns a `MetaProperties` collection.

> Returns a MetaProperties collection that describes the metadata stored
> in the workbook. Read-only.

Looking at its properties and methods, there is a function `GetItemByInternalName()` that returns a `MetaProperty` object.

So, it should be something like this (haven't tested it).

```
Dim props as MetaProperties 
Set props = ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties

Dim prop As MetaProperty
Set prop = props.GetItemByInternalName(DocProp)

Dim value As Variant
value = prop.Value
```

In one line, it should be:

```
GetDocProp = ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties.GetItemByInternalName(DocProp).Value
```

Comment: I tried it as follows:

Function GetDocProp(DocProp As String) As String
GetDocProp = ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties.GetItemByInternalName(DocProp).Value
End Function

And then in Excel I tried =getdocprop("Title") but gives me nothing but '#VALUE!'.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Try to run it in the immediate window to see what it returns: `?ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties.GetItemByInternalName("Title").Value`

Comment: I get a 'compile error invalid use of property', I've tried "Name" instead of "Title" with same negative result.